# Expose Docker api with ciddr limited address

Tags: networking, docker

Is there a way to expose docker api but limiting to a certain part of the local network?

What I would like to do `DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://192.168.250.0/24:2375"`

Comment: Use a firewall.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was waiting to see if there was other answers but since there aren't, put your comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct. It work for me.